# Testing a function inside a component with jest and testing-library

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, testing-library

I'm new with testing-library and jest and I'm trying to test a function inside of the component that changes the value of an input. The component is a form with another component that it's an input.

```
export const Form = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const handleOnSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const form = e.target;
    };
    const inputChange = (param) => (e) => {
        const inputValue = e.target.value;
        setName(inputValue);
    };
    return (
        <form className="form" onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>
            <InputGroup text="name" type="text" value={name} functionality={inputChange("name")}/>
            <Button type="submit"  disabled={name === undefined}/>
        </form>
    );
};

export default Form;
```

The InputGroup Component looks like this

```
export const InputGroup = ({type, id, value, required, functionality, text}) => {
    return (
        <label>{text}</label>
        <input className="input" type={type} id={id} name={id} value={value}
            required={required} onChange={functionality}
        />
    );
};
```

I have tried something like this, but I'm not pretty sure on how to test a function that is directly on the component Form and that it's being passed to the component InputGroup.

```
describe("Form", () => {
    let value;
    let component;
    const handleSubmit = jest.fn();
    const handleChange = ev => {
        ev.preventDefault();
        value = ev.currentTarget.value;
    }
    beforeEach(() => {
        component = render(
            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} functionality={handleChange} />
        );
    });
    it("check error name is triggered", () => {
        const input = component.getByText("name");
        fireEvent.change(input, {target: {value: "aaa"}});
    });
});
```

I get an error thats says "The given element does not have a value setter", so how can I pass the inputChange function to the InputGroup Component?

Comment: i don't understand do you even have a prop `functionality` defined in `Form` or `InputGroup`? If so, post the code as well.

Comment: I have just added the input component @windmaomao. Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks for sharing the `InputGroup`. So you can test the `InputGroup` easily.

```
describe("InputGroup", () => {
  it("check error name is triggered", () => {
    const fn = jest.fn()
    render(<InputGroup functionality={functionality} />)
    fireEvent.change(input, {target: {value: "aaa"}});
    expect(fn).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(...)
  });
});
```

Just an idea. The above code might not run as posted. Ok, now comes to the `Form`. The step might be similar but it might take you some time to get around, but you don't need to test the functionality again, simply because this prop has nothing to do with `Form`. From the form perspective, it only cares `onSubmit`, so you can test against that in the similar way that posted earlier.

Comment: Then how can I test on the Form component that the input is not empty? By default my button is disabled unless the input has a value, and I want to test that too. Thank you, @windmaomao!

Comment: you can test it indirectly in the form through `onSubmit`, or if the form supports a generic `onChange`, you can test against that as well. Basically you should focus on test the direct first level interface property or method, but not all the logic. Otherwise you'll end up a giant integration test. Normally that's not the purpose.

Comment: The onSubmit doesn't get called because the button is disabled as long as the value of the input it's empty. What do you mean with a generic onChange? I'm passing the onChange already with the method "handleChange" but it's not working

Comment: That's correct. you can't test the integration behavior easily. You can have a button to submit the form and then trigger the submission by clicking the button through the test.